# Adding static data( not changing over time) to sequence data in LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, sequence, lstm

I am trying to build a model like the following figure. Please see the following image:

[image: Please see the image]

I want to pass sequence data in LSTM layer and static data (blood group, gender) in another feed forward neural network layer. Later I want to merge them. However, I am confused about the dimenstion here.

- If my understaning is right(which i depict in  the image), how the 5-dimensional sequence data can be merged with 4 dimenstional static data?
- Also, what is the difference of attention mechanism with this structure? (I found in the KERAS documentation that attention mechanism is an way to add static data with sequence data)

Basically, I want  to add  the static data with sequence data. Any other suggestion is apprciated.

Comment: Is the output a sequence or just a final classification?

Comment: The output will be sequence. Actually, I want to measure the prediction accuracy of the next action.

Comment: maybe just flatten the output of lstm and concatenate the static data to it, then put a Dense layer.

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro what do you mean by flattening here? Can  you please provide some detail explanation?

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if I got what you are asking, but I will try.

[image]

Example in `Keras`:

```
static_out = (static_input)

x = LSTM(n_cell_lstm, return_sequences=True)(dynamic_input)
x = Flatten()(x)
dynamic_out = (x)

z = concatenate([dynamic_out, static_out])

z = Dense(64, activation='relu')(z)

main_output = Dense(classes, activation='softmax', name='main_output')(z)
```

Practically you are using an LSTM architecture as you would if you where using only the dynamic data, but at the end you add the info coming from the static data. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Francesco. I realise this is an old question but stumbled across this question and was wondering about something.
In the network described in the image, how would backpropagation work? Would only the loss function of the main output be used to backpropagate through the LSTM network as well? Or would the LSTM be trained independently, and only be concatenated afterwards?

Comment: And in the case that it is backpropagated through the entire network, does it really matter much how many outputs the LSTM part has? Or worded in a better way: how would you determine an optimal amount of outputs for that network?

Comment: The LSTM would train together with the last dense layer, of course nothing would propagate on the static branch because there is nothing to train there. For the latter question, I would try to keep the flattened version of the LSTM output and the static output around the same length, but the best way is just to go with trial and error and decide what is the best ratio between the two output, maybe even considering the importance of the two to the classification/regression prediction.