# LSTM model for multiple sequence group

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, lstm

I have 38 data set and each set contains the different length of sequences(Each of the set contains A-G (7)in different number). This data is from different student to perform a task. So each sequence mainly reflects the same process but different strategy.

```
Group1  Group2............ Group 38
 A        B                   F
 E        C                   A
 B        E                   G
 C        D                   G
 C        F                   F
 D        G                   G
 .        .                   .
 .        .                   .
```

I have converted each group into one hot vector and got  38 nx8 matrix (n is the length of the sequence).
Based on these data I want to implement LSTM/GRU to predict the **next word** in another group. What is the best way to train these data? Currently, I am using these code to calculate the loss:[part of main code]
Suppose,
training dataset: 28[Group 1 - Group 28]
Testing dataset: 10[Rest]

```
 def calc_acc(series, skip=0):[#series will be training and testing data]
        loss = 0
        count = 0

        max_len = np.amax([len(x) for x in series])
        for k in range(min_context, max_len):
            feat = np.array([x[0:k] for x in series if len(x) > k])
            lab = np.array([x[k] for x in series if len(x) > k])
            pred = np.argmax(model.predict(feat), axis=1)
            actual = np.argmax(lab, axis=1)

            count += len(pred)
            loss += sum([x != y for x, y in zip(pred, actual)])

        if count == 0:
            return 1.0
        else:
            return 1. - loss / float(count)
```

I am not sure if it correct or not. I want to train the model in such a way that it first goes to group 1 update its weight and then go to next group[Actually I am not understanding how to train this kind of situation]. My model is follows:

```
def build_model(model, action_size, hidden_size=24, hidden_layers=3, dropout=True, activation='relu'):
  x = Input(shape=(None, action_size+1))#action size is 7(seven word)
  y = x
  y = LSTM(hidden_size if hidden_layers > 1 else action_size, 
  activation='tanh')(y)

  if dropout:
      y = Dropout(0.3)(y)
  if hidden_layers > 1:
      y = Dense(action_size, activation=None)(y)
  y = Activation('softmax')(y)

  return Model(inputs=x,outputs=y)
```

With these I got accuracy 57%.

- Is there any specific method of training this kind of multiple sequence data? Please give suggestion in details
- If I want to add other time-independent features[blood group/gender] like this post[[Adding static data( not changing over time) to sequence data in LSTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53363986/adding-static-data-not-changing-over-time-to-sequence-data-in-lstm]), how can I use the suggested model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clearly stated. Please correct me if I am wrong, I would describe your data as follows.

When you said you have 38 datasets, I guess you are referring to 38 data points or examples. Each data point is a sequence and their length can vary. Each element in a sequence can take 1 of 7 possible discrete values (A-G).

You mentioned, "I want to implement LSTM/GRU to predict the next word in another group" - this statement is completely ambiguous. I suspect, in the example that you provided, for Group1, given `A E B`, you want to predict the next element `C`. Is that correct? Can you clearly provide one input and output example?

Please note, if you have a very small dataset, training an LSTM would be difficult since your neural net model will underfit the data and as a result, you may observe very poor performance. This is applicable in general for machine learning algorithms.

---

> Is there any specific method of training this kind of multiple sequence data? Please give suggestion in details?

Here, I am not sure what did you mean by **multiple sequence data**? If you are not familiar with deep learning, I suggest you study them first to understand why and when you should use them.

> If I want to add other time-independent features [blood group/gender] like this post [Adding static data( not changing over time) to sequence data in LSTM, how can I use the suggested model?

There are several ways. For example, you can learn a vector representation for those features if those features are finite in number. I guess you know about embeddings. You can train `n`-dimensional embeddings for those features. One another alternative can be: adding a value in the sequence representations (like you are using one-hot-vector). Say, `gender` is a binary attribute, so I would append a 0/1 value to the input vector representation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, you are absolutely right about the data. I have 38 data point. For the prediction part, you are also right. Suppose, after training the model, I want to predict each element of the sequence in Group 1. When the first word A given I want to predict the next word. Then given the first two word, predict the next word..and so on. *multiple sequence data**: I mean to say, If I have only one group of say 500 sequences, I would divide training and testing within these group. But for the current case, I have to divide training and testing data within datapoint(group).

Comment: Suppose, my training set contains 37 groups and test set contains 1 groups (LOOCV). For adding time-independet features, I have already done what you have suggested. I converted them to binary attribute and directly added to each of the group's dynamic one hot vector. I want to try another approach. I have found a method as described in the post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53363986/adding-static-data-not-changing-over-time-to-sequence-data-in-lstm]I reffered. But I am facing problem  to implement the suggested model